# Unreal Engine Naming Conventions

Tags: naming-conventions, unreal-engine4

I see that there's a pattern to how some things are named:

```
AActor
UObject
UPrimitiveComponent
```

...and I see that the pattern is defined [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/), but is there anything I should infer beyond the inheritance chain ? Is this the Unreal take on Hungarian Notation ? Or are the prefixes just for ease of identifying objects.

Comment: As the doc says "UnrealHeaderTool requires the correct prefixes in most cases, so it's important to provide them.", so I'd say it's a more like a "systematic" reason for those prefix than Hungarian Notation.